# Error while reading integers using fread in C

Tags: c, integer, output, fread

I have written the following C code to read 5 integers from an input file:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){
  FILE *fp;
  unsigned *ch;
  unsigned i,n=5;

  ch=(unsigned*)malloc(n*sizeof(unsigned));
  fp=fopen("input","r");
  fread(ch ,sizeof(unsigned),n,fp);
  fclose(fp);
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("\n%u ",ch[i]);
  free(ch);  
  return 0;
}
```

The input file is:

```
1 2 3 4 58
```

But the output I am getting is:

```
540155953 
540287027 
14389 
0 
0
```

Please help me out.

Comment: You have a fundamental misunderstanding of how data is stored. You have a text file. Which means the data is stored as ascii characters. So you cannot read them as integers.

Comment: read as text. e.g. `for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
   fscanf(fp, "%u", &ch[i]);`

Comment: Is it not possible to read integer/double variables using fread function from a text file?

Comment: No it is not. By definition a text file only contains ascii characters and not binary data like integers/doubles. Use `fscanf` if you want to read text input and have it parsed as a different type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[fread](http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/c-reference/fread-function/) and fwrite are used for binary files.  Data in a binary file is interpreted as bytes as they would appear in memory as opposed to text files which can be read by humans.  Using the `hexdump` command on linux, we can see the hexadecimal values for your input file

```
$ hexdump -C input
00000000  31 20 32 20 33 20 34 20  35 38 0a
```

Using the hex column of the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), you can see that 0x31 is the 1 character, 0x20 is a space character, etc.  But because `fread` interprets the data in the file as binary, it will read 4 bytes for each `unsigned int`.  You can check that 0x20322031 (the first 4 bytes in the file in reverse order) is equal to 540155953.

If you want to generate the data in the file in binary and subsequently read it, you can use

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){
  FILE *fp;
  unsigned *ch;
  unsigned i,n=5;

  unsigned int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,58};

  ch=(unsigned*)malloc(n*sizeof(unsigned));
  fp=fopen("input","w+");
  fwrite(arr,sizeof(unsigned),n,fp); /* write binary */
  fseek(fp, SEEK_SET, 0); /* move file cursor back to the start of the file */
  fread(ch ,sizeof(unsigned),n,fp); /* read binary */
  fclose(fp);
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("\n%u ",ch[i]);
  free(ch);  
  return 0;
}
```

and examine the file called `input` to see the differences.

As noted in the comments, you can [`fscanf`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fscanf.htm) with a `%u` specifier to grab `unsigned int`s if you want to interpret the data as a text file.

Comment: This is just a dupe. Please refrain from answering questions that are a duplicate or need closing.

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ Did you downvote the answer?

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ This is a good answer. Please refrain from downvoting answers that are useful or answer the question.

Comment: @2501 I agree that this is a good answer, and a lot better than the answer to the dupe I linked to. I would upvote it if it would be an answer to the original question I linked to. The only reason I downvoted it is that you should refrain from answering dupes. It encourages the OP to ask more dupes without searching.

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ the answer is really helpful & my question is not a duplicate one. The  dupe was related to a structure variable & mine is a lot simple problem.

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ You're trying to game the system. You get one close vote. Downvoting on correct answers to exert pressure to close the question is crooked.

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ Futhermore, the decision whether the question is a dup, is not made by you, but by the community. It is called voting to close and it requires 5 votes. Only then it is a duplicate. As it stands only you think this is a dup.

Comment: I was answering trying to enlighten on the specific numerics in this case and to show that it was a valid output in a different interpretation.  However, your point is taken @AshishAhujaツ

Comment: @loganrakai If you ever want to answer any question, please do it. Even if this were a duplicate, and it isn't, the answer would still be useful.

Comment: At the end of the day, I'm glad to help you @user6607311

Comment: @2501 can we [continue this discussion](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123626/room-for-discussion-on-stackoverflow-com-questions-39554724-error-while-reading-i) in chat? I don't think we should have long discussions in comments

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ I have already said everything that needed to be said. Feel free to disagree, but this discussion is *over*.

Comment: @2501 I agree with some of your points, not all.

Comment: @loganrakai thank you very much